# C Function returning too slowly sometimes

Tags: c, performance, apache, function

I'm writing an apache module and I have a function here that takes an IP address (defined in myip) and checks the apache table (defined as iplist) to see if the IP address exists.

This is the code I use to let apache load my lines from the httpd.conf file add them to the IP address list table:

```
const char *exempt_ip(cmd_parms *cmd,void *cfg,const char *arg){
    dir_config *conf=(dir_config*)cfg;
    if (conf){
        char ip[7]="XXXXXXX";
        snprintf(ip,sizeof(ip),"IP%i",config.numIPs);
        apr_table_set(conf->iplist,ip,arg);
        config.numIPs++;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

And this is the code that is causing the server to respond slowly at times even on a table having only 4 keys and 4 values in it, yet it does work:

```
const int ip_matched(apr_table_t* iplist,const char* myip){
    const char* v;char ip[7]="XXXXXXX";int ret=0;
    int ic;
    for (ic=1;ic<config.numIPs;ic++){
        snprintf(ip,sizeof(ip),"IP%i",ic);
        v=apr_table_get(iplist,ip);
        if (strcmp(v,myip)==0){
            ret=1;
            ic=config.numIPs+1;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Maybe there are faster native C functions I can use? Anyone have any idea?

Comment: How many IPs are in the table you're searching?

Comment: At the moment, only 4. But I notice somewhat of a performance improvement by changing the max size from 7 to 4 in char ip. I'll be happy if I can store up to a few thousand IP's.

Comment: "Somewhat"? Can you quantify the difference?

Comment: Sometimes the loading takes no time at all, and other times, loading time takes a bit longer. I'm starting to wonder if my browser is the fault

Comment: I see a bug. Use `char ip[8] = "XXXXXXX";` and `sizeof(ip)-1`. You forgot about the null-character that terminates strings in C.

Comment: @Mike is the function `exempt_ip()` supposed to have a loop? Why have you incremented the number of items with `config.numIPs++;`? And in `ip_matched()` why have you run the loop `for (ic=1; ...` from `1` and not from `0`?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey I thought that at first, but the string created seems to be shorter, eg "IP3".

Comment: @Mike Run some quantitative benchmarks before you assume there's actually anything wrong here. At the moment, it's not clear that there's any problem.

Comment: @WeatherVane: The string created might typically be shorter, but in the case that it isn't, the string is unterminated, which is almost guaranteed to be a bug, or at least a sleeper.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey in the range `ic<=7`, the function `snprintf(ip,sizeof(ip),"IP%i",ic);` will create a string requiring 4 bytes, with 7 allocated.

Comment: @WeatherVane: You're right, of course. It's just that for me, the nth programming commandment says try not to make correctness depend on stuff that just happens to be so, but might easily get changed :)

Comment: @MikeDunlavey you are right too - I posted an **answer** similar to your comment before deleting it!

Comment: @WeatherVane: I saw it. In fact I still see it, but it's gray - I've got enough rep. If you had left it up, I would have upvoted it.

Comment: I better do more benchmarks. I think the browser is the culprit here.

Answer (score 2):

In both functions,

```
char ip[7]="XXXXXXX";
```

holds 7 chars but no terminator, they should be

```
char ip[8]="XXXXXXX";
```

or

```
char ip[]="XXXXXXX";
```

But I know this isn't really an adequate answer.